# WinApi LineTo not refreshing the line

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I'm just starting learning C++. All I want to do is drawing a line to a specified coord, which comes as an input in a method. I set the starting point in each loop (calling this function in a loop with different arguments) using `MoveToEx` and giving the coordinates in which I want lane to be drawn.

Any ideas how to make it working in a loop?

My code is similar to:

```
void Clock::drawSecondLine(float x,float y) {
    HWND console_handle = GetConsoleWindow();
    HDC device_context = GetDC(console_handle);
    HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3, RGB(255, 0, 0));
    SelectObject(device_context, pen);

    MoveToEx(device_context, 0, 0, NULL);
    Ellipse(device_context, 400, 0, 0, 400);
    MoveToEx(device_context, 200, 200, NULL);
    LineTo(device_context, (int)x, (int)y);

    ReleaseDC(console_handle, device_context);
    cin.ignore();
}
```

And the loop:

```
void Zegar::startClock() {
    while (true) {
        drawSecondLine(laneShowingSecond.getX(), laneShowingSecond.getY());
        laneShowingSecond.movePointByRadius(RADIUS_PER_SECOND);
        Sleep(1000);
        increaseSecond();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the values of x and y? Also, you are leaking the pen which will mean you eventually run out of GDI objects.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to be drawing on the console window...

Comment: You should create a GUI app. But it works with the console window (as long as you don't "touch" it at runtime). First, you could move anything that doesn't depend on `x` and `y` outside the method (and also the loop - especially the DC creation/destruction). The method should only contain `LineTo` (obviously, you don't need a method for that). Also, __you are not checking functions return codes!!!__ (meaning that something might go wrong but you assume it went right, and that could trigger an endless stream of problems, including crashes).

Comment: You are drawing (__backwards__, since bounding rectangle _right_ dimension is smaller than its _left_ one) an ellipse with _xRadius_ = _yRadius_ = 100, centered to _C(200, 200)_, then from its center you draw a line to _(`x`, `y`)_ (which I assume is on the circle). Then, every second you are drawing a line. What's the final shape looking like? A bunch of circle radii, or a poly bounded by the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some sample code (which I am running in *VStudio 2k10*).

**Notes**:

- Although it is compiled as *C++* (and uses some *C++* features like `iostream` - meaning that it won't compile as *C*), it's still plain old *C*.
- It has a lot of ugly stuff and *NO-NO* s (like global vars, lots defines, mixture of *C* and *C++* code, drawing on the console window, ...). The goal was to have a *PoC*; the code can be cleansed later.
- From the bounding rectangle (`RECT_*` defines *(400, 0, 0, 400)*) I am extracting the center coordinates, and the radii on the *X* and *Y* axes, using some simple mathematical calculations (due to the fact that the rectangle is a square, the 2 radii are equal so we hit the **particular case where the ellipse is actually a circle**).
- `nextPoint` function is the replacement of `laneShowingSecond.getX(), laneShowingSecond.getY()` from your code.
- Everything that needs to be only executed once (at the beginning) is placed in the `init` function. Note that if something goes wrong during initialization, it exits with an *error* (*< 0*) code, since it won't be able to draw.
- Similarily, any cleanup stuff to be performed at the end is placed in the `cleanup` function (here I didn't bother to check for return codes since it's exiting anyway).
- The `draw` function contains the drawing *loop*. In every iteration:

  - The angle is incremented by `INCERMENT_DEG` (which by default is 30°).
  - The next point on the ellipse is calculated using some simple trigonometrical formulas.
  - The drawing is performed.
  - A wait of `ITERATION_SLEEP_TIME` milliseconds (I've set it to 200 to avoid waiting one second for each line drawn) takes place.
  - Note that:

    - It stops after reaching 360° or *2 * PI Radians* (round-the-clock), because it doesn't make sense to draw the same lines over and over again.
    - The drawing is performed counter-clockwise (positive angles in trigonometry); also the *xOy* origin (*O(0, 0)*) is screen's upper left corner.
- Play with the defines that I marked with comments, by assigning various values to them and see how the drawing changes.

*main.cpp*:

```
#include <iostream>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define RECT_LEFT 400  // Modify any of these 4 RECT_* values to get different ellipse shapes.
#define RECT_TOP 0
#define RECT_RIGHT 0
#define RECT_BOT 400

#define ITERATION_SLEEP_TIME 200  // Sleep time while in loop.

#define INCERMENT_DEG 30  // 30 degrees per step; a full circle has 360 (2 * PI  RAD).
#define M_PI_180 M_PI / 180

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

typedef enum {DRAW_RADII, DRAW_POLY} DrawMethod;

const int radiusX = abs(RECT_RIGHT - RECT_LEFT) / 2;
const int radiusY = abs(RECT_BOT - RECT_TOP) / 2;
const int centerX = (RECT_RIGHT + RECT_LEFT) / 2;
const int centerY = (RECT_BOT + RECT_TOP) / 2;

HWND hwnd = NULL;
HDC hdc = NULL;
HPEN hpen = NULL;

DrawMethod meth = DRAW_RADII;  // Modify this to DRAW_POLY to draw a polygon instead of the "bike wheel".

int deg = 0;
double x = 0, y = 0;


void nextPoint(int degree, double *x, double *y) {
    *x = centerX + radiusX * cos(M_PI_180 * degree );
    *y = centerY - radiusY * sin(M_PI_180 * degree);
}

int init() {
    if ((hwnd = GetConsoleWindow()) == NULL) {
        cout << "GetConsoleWindow error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    if ((hdc = GetDC(hwnd)) == NULL) {
        cout << "GetDC error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return -2;
    }
    if ((hpen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3, RGB(255, 0, 0))) == NULL) {
        cout << "CreatePen error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return -3;
    }
    SelectObject(hdc, hpen);
    Ellipse(hdc, RECT_LEFT, RECT_TOP, RECT_RIGHT, RECT_BOT);
    nextPoint(deg, &x, &y);
    if (meth == DRAW_RADII) {
        MoveToEx(hdc, centerX, centerY, NULL);
        LineTo(hdc, (int)x, (int)y);
    } else if (meth == DRAW_POLY) {
        MoveToEx(hdc, (int)x, (int)y, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}

void draw() {
    while (deg < 360) {
        deg += INCERMENT_DEG;
        nextPoint(deg, &x, &y);
        if (meth == DRAW_RADII) {
            MoveToEx(hdc, centerX, centerY, NULL);
            LineTo(hdc, (int)x, (int)y);
        } else if (meth == DRAW_POLY) {
            LineTo(hdc, (int)x, (int)y);
        } else
            break;
        Sleep(ITERATION_SLEEP_TIME);
    }
}

void cleanup() {
    if (hpen) {
        DeleteObject(hpen);
    }
    if (hwnd && hdc) {
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
    }
}

int main() {
    if (!init())
        draw();
    cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```